# Jquery code refreshing whole page instead of a part of a page

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    interval = setInterval(updateDiv, 1000);
});

function updateDiv() {
    var letest_id = $("ul.pagination1 :first-child").attr('id').replace('record-', '');

    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: 'url.php?load_s=ajax&group_id=<?php echo $g_i_s;?>&max_id=' + letest_id + '&ref=<?php echo time();?>',

        success: function (data) {

            if (data) {
                $('ul.pagination1').prepend(data).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        },

        error: function () {

            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
    var comid = $('#last_id_ajax').val();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        url: 'url.php?group_id=<?php echo $g_i_s;?>&commentid=' + comid + '&ref=<?php echo time();?>',
        success: function (result) {
            if (result) {
                var divi = $(result).find(".imgd").attr('alt');
                var last_id_ajax_val = $(result).find(".cid").attr('id');
                $('#last_id_ajax').val(last_id_ajax_val);
                // alert(newcoment);
                $(divi).append(result).fadeIn('slow');
            }
        },

        error: function () {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    });
}
```

Hi I am using this code to refresh files I have put in a wall system and then I am getting this file (main index file where this code is used) to show up in a block, My purpose was to only refresh the block where i am calling index file, but this code is also making favicon to blink every few seconds and i  also see the browser showing waiting for www.mywebsite.com every few seconds, how can I fix it to only update the part of block and not the whole page. I hope this makes sense as this is my first post here and thank you in advance.

### Edited

tried to update as per suggestion but it doesn't work and i know it's messed up

```
$(document).ready(
```

function update() 
{
    var letest_id = $("ul.pagination1 :first-child").attr('id').replace('record-','');
$.ajax({
      method:'GET', 
       cache: false,
             url: '/Themes/default/fbcommentstyle/latest_post.php?load_s=ajax&group_id=&max_id='+letest_id+'&ref=',

```
     success: function(data){

     if(data){ 
       $('ul.pagination1').prepend(data).fadeIn('slow');
     }
     },

  error:function(){
    clearTimeout(updateDiv);
  }
});
 var comid = $('#last_id_ajax').val();
      $.ajax({
      method:'GET', 
       cache: false,
      url: '/Themes/default/fbcommentstyle/latest_comment.php?group_id=<?php echo $g_i_s;?>&commentid='+comid+'&ref=<?php echo time();?>',
      success: function(result){
         if(result){
              var divi = $(result).find(".imgd").attr('alt');
              var last_id_ajax_val = $(result).find(".cid").attr('id');
               $('#last_id_ajax').val(last_id_ajax_val);

                $(divi).append(result).fadeIn('slow');
             }
      },

      error:function(){
         clearTimeout(updateDiv);
      }
   } 3000);
```

}

Comment: I would strongly recommend using setTimeout and having your ajax success function call updateDiv() again rather than using setInterval. Especially with an ajax request and especially at 1s intervals, you're going to start getting bleedovers before long.

Comment: @swornabsent can you please fix it in the code i provided, i tried this but it did not work for me, and thank you for your reply.

Comment: any help will be appreciated, Thanks!